# Flask-testing - why the test does fail

Tags: python, flask, flask-testing

I'm trying to write tests for a simple Flask application. Structure of the project is following:

```
app/
    static/
    templates/
    forms.py
    models.py
    views.py
migrations/
config.py
manage.py
tests.py
```

tests.py

```
import unittest
from app import create_app, db
from flask import current_app
from flask.ext.testing import TestCase

class AppTestCase(TestCase):
    def create_app(self):
        return create_app('test_config')

    def setUp(self):
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()

    def test_hello(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assert_200(response)
```

app/**init**.py

```
# app/__init__.py

from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import config

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    db.init_app(app)
    return app

app = create_app('default')

from . import views
```

When I launch the tests, test_hello fails because response.status_code is 404. Tell me, please, how can I fix it? It seems, that app instance doesn't know anything about view functions in the views.py. If it needs the whole code, it can be found [here](https://github.com/Stright/course_project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `views.py` file mount the routes in the `app` created in your `__init__.py` file.

You must bind these routes to your created app in `create_app` test method.

I suggest you to invert the dependency. Instead the `views.py` import your code, you can make a `init_app` to be imported and called from your `__init__.py` or from the test file.

```
# views.py
def init_app(app):
    app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', index)
    # repeat to each route
```

You can do better than that, using a [Blueprint](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#blueprint-objects).

```
def init_app(app):
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
```

This way, your test file can just import this `init_app` and bind the blueprint to the test `app` object.

Comment: If I'll use blueprints, it may be better to register blueprints inside create_app function in my case?

Comment: Yes, blueprint is the best way to handle Flask routes